# Use of Unresolved Identifer in scheduledTimer

Tags: timer

I've been working on this for a day and can't figure out what is going wrong.  I've searched here and the documentation and still can't find the answer.

Here's the code:

```
`var counter = 60
 let timer = scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1.0, target: Any?, #selector(timerAction), userInfo: Any?, repeats: true)

 func timerAction() {
    for i in timer {
        counter -= 1
        print(counter)
  }
```

}
   timerAction()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.